# Sitecore - Restrict item by Data Template Type on a Field

Tags: sitecore

I would like to restrict the data type of items a user can select on a field. I can do this by Insert Options of tree node in the field's source, but this feels a little open to abuse - say a developer accidentally moves an item of the wrong type under this node then the system falls down. I am possibly over worrying this, but in other CMS I have had the ability to restrict the type of an item a user can select. What is the best way to go about this.

Comment: You shouldn't have to worry about developers breaking the source of template fields, this *is* something that you should prevent your content editors from being able to break though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the field types like `Treelist` or `Multilist` you can set the `source` parameter of field with additional parameters like `IncludeTemplatesForSelection`, e.g.

```
DataSource=/sitecore/content/home/employees&IncludeTemplatesForSelection=Employee
```

Here is a post explaining [how to use `source`](http://sitecoreadventures.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/using-source-property.html) and here is another one called [Tame your Sitecore treelist](http://firebreaksice.com/tame-your-sitecore-treelists/).

Answer (score 5):

I actually wrote a [blog post](http://zacharykniebel.com/blog/2014/June/26/Constraining-the-Sitecore-7-Multilist-and-Treelist-Fields-with-and-without-Search) the other day that includes information for filtering the Treelist, Multilist, Treelist with Search, and Multilist with Search (everything you need for Sitecore 6-7).

I think you would be most interested in the following parameters for the Treelist and Multilist:

1. `IncludeTemplatesForSelection` - *Users can only select items based on this comma-separated list of data template names*
2. `ExcludeTemplatesForSelection` - *Users cannot select items based on this comma-separated list of data template names*
3. `IncludeTemplatesForDisplay` - *Users can view items based on this comma-separated list of data template names and IDs*
4. `ExcludeTemplatesForDisplay` - *Users cannot view items based on this comma-separated list of data template names and IDs*
5. `IncludeItemsForDisplay` - *Users can view items based on this comma-separated list of item names and IDs*
6. `ExcludeItemsForDisplay` - *Users cannot view items based on this comma-separated list of item names and IDs*

For the Treelist with Search and Multilist with Search, take a look at the following:

1. `Filter` - *Note that there is a bug in Sitecore 7.0 when using this parameter to filter templates that I discussed in another [blog post](http://zacharykniebel.com/blog/2014/July/16/Bug-with-Filtering-by-Template-Name-in-Sitecore-7s-Multilist-with-Search-Field)*
2. `TemplateFilter` - *Discussed in the post for the bug discussed above, as a workaround*